# Git push stuck after total when using terminal?

Tags: git, github

I try to push some file to Github and total size is only 22.2M. I don't know why it stuck after the total line. I've read the [Git push hangs when pushing to Github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16906161/git-push-hangs-when-pushing-to-github) and tried each answer but it doesn't work at all. Does it works fine? Do I have any method to accelerate this process?

```
Counting objects: 203, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (176/176), done.
Writing objects: 100% (203/203), 22.12 MiB | 15.70 MiB/s, done.
Total 203 (delta 23), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

Comment: Your output shows a completed push.  It's not clear what if anything is happening at that point.

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702731/git-fails-when-pushing-commit-to-github

Comment: If a push is successful, it'll show sth. like `To https://github.com/project
   fb0ba24..b6b5d9  master -> master`. This time it doesn't.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I encountered the same issue on one of my repos when trying to push a number of larger commits at once. Multiple attempts wouldn't proceed past the *Total* output row. I first tried a couple of things suggested in other questions:

- Increasing the http buffer size, `git config --global http.postBuffer 150000000` (~150MB)
- Waiting 8 hours in case of issues at Github's server

Neither seemed to help. Git push still wouldn't get past the 'Total' line in the terminal, no matter how long I waited.

**Solution**:
After taking a precautionary backup, I issued the garbage collection command to the repo:

```
git gc
```

The next `git push` then worked immediately.

Comment: The first approach, setting http.postBuffer, solved it for me. `git gc` had no effect.

Comment: Brilliant! This worked on first attempt

Answer (score 0):

I found that setting the upstream origin solved it for me.

```
git push --set-upstream origin branchName
```

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes there may be an error caused by the terminal. Closing and reopening the terminal solved the problem for me.