# Bitbucket stuck after git push

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

when I use git push to my repository on bitbucket, git stuck with:

```
Counting objects: 70, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (60/60), done.
Writing objects: 100% (70/70), 84.86 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 70 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
```

and stays here forever... I use credentials form login/pass, ssh, reinstall git and nothing. The repository is from the company that I work for, but I can create and clone repos...

Comment: what does the 'git push --verbose' say?

Comment: arning: push.default is unset; its implicit value has changed in
Git 2.0 from 'matching' to 'simple'. To squelch this message
and maintain the traditional behavior, use:

  git config --global push.default matching

To squelch this message and adopt the new behavior now, use:

  git config --global push.default simple
...

Comment: well but use your branch and remote, in the same way as you used it with the normal git push

Comment: I don't understand, I tried "git push --set-upstream origin master" and nothing change. I can commit to github, but not for bitbucket =/

Answer (score 1):

I believe this question has already been replied [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68711337/9431254)

Basically, you need to increase your default git configuration 'http.postBuffer' (command -> git config --global http.postBuffer 157286400)