# Pushing to git inside pipenv

Tags: git, pipenv

I have created a pipenv location for django and have created and git repo in that location. I added and commited the repo. I have added the remote url needed but when i try to push to the remote repo, It hangs at "Total". I have confirmed that everything is set up on the server side as without pipenv, i cant push without issue.

does pipenv confuse git?

Edit:

I will make note that I had similar issues with just virtualenv. It appears that git has trouble pushing a virtual environment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git push hangs after Total line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15843937/git-push-hangs-after-total-line)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+hangs+Total

Comment: I thought the same issue but it works just fine without Pipenv.

Answer (score 1):

The answer turned out to because of the remote git path.

the path was '/repos/django/[gitproject].git'

Django saw the word 'django' in the path and was trying to interoperate it as a command.

after I removed 'django' from my path. I had no issues pushing. 
Looking back, this makes sense as django warns you when making a project with the word 'django' in it.

Sorry for the confusion.