# how to undo a hundreds previous commit

Tags: git, github

I have written a pull-to-refresh feature and committed to Github already. That feature with 1.3.0 and already released in a new product version. Now I fireguard out some code I have modified of this feature is not well optimized, so I want to undo it now. I am about to release 1.4.0 now, so there are nearly hundreds of commits after that commits.

After googling I find some answers about reverting previous commit. But my problem is how to revert the almost hundreds times previous commits.

I tried to compared the differences by diff tool via git plugin of Eclipse, but found without any result because I move the original file to another package.

I feel really confused about that, do I have to undo it line by line?

---

EDIT
What I want to do is more like merging the long time ago commit to the latest commit. Because I added new features to my latest commit and I don`t mean to lose them, meanwhile, I want to revert back some feature as well.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier to:

- create a branch *before* those commits you want to revert,
- [`git cherry-pick`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) all the commits of your current branch you want to keep: that will replay them on top of your branch, which has none of the commits you want to avoid.

Remember, you can [cherry-pick a range of commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1994491/6309).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I am new to git, and I don\`t know how to use `git cherry-pick` correctly.

Comment: @LoganGuo that is why I mention the link http://stackoverflow.com/a/1994491/6309 in my answer. I would doing a backup of your repo first, then experimenting.

Answer (score 1):

I would first create an ' undo branch'  of the current branch and than do a `git rebase -i HEAD~XXX`. The undo branch is not necessary, but if something goes wrong you can just delete it.

```
git checkout -b undo
git rebase -i HEAD~100
```

Replace `HEAD~100` with the number of commits you want to go back in history. Alternatively you can also use a specific commit.

```
git rebase -i <commitid>
```

This will open the rebase interactive editor. Just delete the commits that you don't want by removing the `pick <commitid>` line.

Also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/27076194/974186 for details about rebase interactive.

If you removed the commits from your `undo` branch and everything looks fine you can just point the original branch to the new rewritten history.

```
git checkout originalBranch
git reset --hard undo
```

Now you can push the changes, but it might be necessary to do a forced push. Git will normally reject the remote branch update if it is not in line. Take care if you do a forced bush, since you overwrite the remote branch and commits done in the meanwhile gets lost.