# Similar trick to git bisect WITHIN a commit

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-bisect

With git bisect we can zoom in on when a problem might have been introduced between commits.

I was wondering if there is also a way to have git go through (combinations) of files within a *single* commit, so you can figure out which file / part is causing the trouble?

Comment: Nope, but this is a good argument for making frequent small commits rather than single very large commits.

Comment: Is this a hypothetical question or is there an actual problem you're trying to solve?  There might be another way to approach the problem.

Comment: @larsks I knew that comment would come :-)  (and it is correct).

Comment: @R0MANARMY It is based on last week, where a bug was introcuted, I soon discovered in which commit it was, but it took me a long time to find out the exact file. If git would just propose some files and check in etc, then all I'd have to do is reload the page to check the bug.

Comment: @larsks My main problem is usually that changing one file is usually part of a bigger plan. Would you really commit 1 file when the success of this single file depends on changes in other files?

Comment: @PascalvKooten Generally no, you wouldn't commit one file unless it represented all the work related to a particular feature or work item.  If you often find yourself in a situation where a single work item results in large commits, you may try to see if work items can be broken down further.

Answer (score 2):

The [recommended way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2118107/623735) to [split a commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217156/break-a-previous-commit-into-multiple-commits) is with `git rebase -i $commit_you_want_to_split^`. Chop up your commit with the `edit` rebase action then a `reset HEAD^` and a bunch of `git add`s to insert your new smaller commits into the index. Admittedly this isn't automatic, but you might be able to script it with a lot of `sed` or `awk` or python. See the the SO links above for more details.

Once your commit is chopped up, your `git bisect` will now be much more precise.

Has anyone automated this process?