# Can git automatically split up a commit into single hunks?

Tags: git, bash

[As explained in previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217156/break-a-previous-commit-into-multiple-commits), you can split up commits into smaller patches. However, these answers recommend `git add -p`, which does the job but is tedious if all I want is to have one commit per hunk, in the given order in the file. Is there some way to achieve just that, automatically?

Comment: In case you're wondering why I need this: I have a huge commit, due to a change by an automatic code-formatting tool. This caused a runtime bug; if each hunk were in its own commit I could easily use `git bisect` to find it.

Comment: What would be a rule to delimit hunks? One file = one commit?

Comment: @NickVolynkin: I'd be ok with the hunks that `git add -p` offers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do something like

```
echo -e "y\nq" | git add -p && git commit -m "automated"
```

which does:

echo y (accept first hunk), then q (quit) for the next hunk, commit with the given message.

Loop until `git commit` does not return success:

```
s=0 
i=1
while [ $s -eq 0 ]
do 
  echo -e "y\nq" | git add -p && git commit -m "automated $i"
  s=$?
  let i=$i+1
done
```

or in one line:

```
s=0; i=0; while [ $s -eq 0 ]; do echo -e "y\nq" | git add -p && git commit -m "automated $i"; s=$?; let i=$i+1; done
```

Produces commits like

```
c5ba3 - (HEAD) automated 3
14da0 - automated 2
6497b - automated 1
```

Comment: More a `bash` / `sh` solution than `git`, seems rather hackish, but I'd be ok with that if no native alternative is available.

Comment: isn't `addp` a typo or an alias?

Comment: @leftaroundabout yes, I thought so, but it worked nicely for my small test ;).

Comment: Change `echo -e "y\nq"` to `echo -e "s\ny\nq"` for even smaller Hunks.

Comment: In two lines, where you just repeat the second manually until it's done: `i=1`, `echo -e "y\nq" | git add -p && git commit -m "automated $i"; let i=i+1`