# Break a previous git commit into smaller commits using SourceTree

Tags: git, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

In this question: [Break a previous commit into multiple commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217156/break-a-previous-commit-into-multiple-commits), there are steps to split a commit using `git rebase -i HEAD~3`.  This looks like it works, but is there a way to accomplish this from the SourceTree GUI?

Answer (score 4):

You can reset the branch to one specific commit (right click on commit) and select the Mixed (or Soft) mode, make you new commits and make a forced push.

Your branch:[image: Scenario]

Right click on specific commit:
[image: Right Click]

Select mode:
[image: Mixed mode]

Then you will have your branch based on the commit selected. The files of the others commits will be ready for make new commits. 
[image: result]

Now you can make the new commits as you want.

And then to make the changes in origin (and erase the others commits ie, override the history) you will have to force your push.
[image: focre push]

Comment: Force push to master, ftw.