# Git split inital commit into 2

Tags: git

My repository has one branch and a number of different commits. The initial commit contains some code. I want to create a pull request of current branch but to an earlier version then the initial commit so that I can view the whole relevant code that has been added. How can I split a commit to 2?

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217156/break-a-previous-commit-into-multiple-commits

Answer (score 4):

You can follow the procedure described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6217314/26396) to ["*How to break a previous commit into multiple commits*"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6217156/26396) with the exception that you need to add the `--root` switch, since you want to modify the first commit in your branch.

From [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#git-rebase---root):

> **--root**
>   Rebase *all* commits reachable from <branch>, instead of limiting them
>   with an <upstream>. This allows you to rebase the root commit(s) on a
>   branch.

For example, assuming you wanted to modify the initial commit in `master`, you would say:

```
git checkout master
git rebase -i --root
```

Comment: When I tried this I found that this requires `git reset HEAD~` on the root commit which hits an error: `unknown revision of path not in working tree`.

Comment: We found a way to do this by adding a dummy commit and reordering, then removing that dummy commit. Details here: https://gist.github.com/gngdb/52db51778d814cc48fd2ec94d7727beb