# How can I copy many files, defined by extension, in many folders, from one remote repository branch to another?

Tags: git, branch, commit, restore, merge-conflict-resolution

It seems, I have changed not only my backend files on the remote branch, but also many frontend files. Now they are changed in my branch and I can't merge it to the master branch.

How can I copy files chosen by extension from one branch into another?

1. I am on the feature branch.
2. The numerous *.html files in the project and on the feature branch are bad.
3. There are many useful current changes in .java and .xml on the feature branch.
4. I want to get all *.html files from the current master branch and put them into the current project. Or to the feature branch.

Comment: So you want to just throw away the changes in the destination branch, for files with those file extensions?

Comment: Yes,  exactly...

Answer (score 0):

Git does not allow the partial merging of branches. That is, when you merge you need to merge all the information - you can't ignore some files and include others... (well, you can, but it's very bad practice and involves just pretending you did a merge).

That said, there are several ways you can proceed.

You can ignore the fact that your branch is on a remote - in git branches are branches, irrespective of where they are. A `git pull`/`fetch` will download your remote changes so you can work on them.

## 1) Simple - Ignore history

This involves taking all your changes in your feature branch, adding only those with the extension, and making a large commit with those changes on `master`:

- `git checkout feature`
- `git reset master..feature` - reset to the intersection of `master` and `feature`
- `git add -- *.txt` - add all the `.txt` files
- `git commit`
- (`git reset --hard` to eliminate the files you don't want)
- `git merge`

## 2) Complex - Preserving history

- Use `git rebase -i` to [interactively break each commit into 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217156/break-a-previous-commit-into-multiple-commits) - those that edit the `.txt` files (for example), and those that don't.
- After, use `git cherry-pick` to take only the commits that you want into a new branch, called `feature-txt-files-only` for example.
- Merge this with your `master` branch.

Comment: I see that your first 4 lines overwrite the old content on the intersection by the wrong current content?

Comment: Yes, but all the 'correct' content is saved in git, so a `git reset --hard` will fix that. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

I will give an example for `.py` files. Try to do the merge, then

```
find -name '*.py' -print0|xargs -0 git checkout --ours --
```

or

```
find -name '*.py' -print0|xargs -0 git checkout --theirs --
```

"Ours" means the local branch, and "theirs" means the remote branch (except when rebasing, when their meanings are swapped).

You can do this as many times as necessary for the file types you want to use to clobber the other changes.

Then finish the merge in the normal way.

The only problem is this might not work reliably with files that have been deleted on one of the branches but changed on the other branch. So watch out for such cases.

Comment: "error: pathspec './Projects/Examples/src/test/resources/SendEmailPreCreatedHtml/html_content.html' did not match any file(s) known to git." That is what I am getting for every file. Have you tried your command yourself?

Comment: Why are those files not known to git? Are they files deleted in one branch but modified in the other? Are they new files? Or are they files that git should be, or is, ignoring?

Comment: The exact command line was: "find -name '*.html' -print0|xargs -0 git checkout origin/develop
". These files are normal html files. They are known to grid when I use GridExtension.

Comment: Huh? What is grid? What is GridExtension?

Comment: Some graphic GIT interface by which I can check by right click if a file is in git or not. I think, that is the most quick way.