# GitLab Secondary Geo code push fails with Internal API unreachable

Tags: git, gitlab, ubuntu-16.04

Code size is `6GB`. While trying to push to secondary geo node from git client system, it fails with below error.

```
git push -u origin master
remote:
remote: You're pushing to a Geo secondary! We'll help you by proxying this
remote: request to the primary:
remote:
remote:   ssh://git@ssh.gitlab-primary.domain.com:443/upload_grp/upload_from_secondary_geo.git
remote:
Enumerating objects: 175198, done.
Counting objects: 100% (175198/175198), done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (114761/114761), done.
Writing objects: 100% (175198/175198), 1.40 GiB | 103.54 MiB/s, done.
Total 175198 (delta 50871), reused 175198 (delta 50871)
remote:
remote: ========================================================================
remote:
remote: Internal API unreachable
remote:
remote: ========================================================================
remote:
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Is it something related with network related problem? Any direction to fix the problem would help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like the new way to display an internal GitLab server error, as [introduced with GitLab 12.5+ (Nov. 2019)](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-shell/-/merge_requests/334)

That needs to be checked at the GitLab server level, to see if its log includes any clue.
That being said, make sure the commit pushed itself if not 6GB... that would likely be rejected on its own (too big)

The [OP Kishore](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4948798/kishore) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60445691/gitlab-secondary-geo-code-push-fails-with-internal-api-unreachable/60445744?noredirect=1#comment106933985_60445744):

> I tried with 6-GB code where as it didn’t work, Later 662M & 1.4-GB code I could able to push successfully.

The solution remains to [break your large commit in multiple smaller ones](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6217156/6309).

Comment: /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-shell/gitlab-shell.log, /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/application.log
/var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log  doesn't show any error messages.

Comment: i could able to push small code(662M) successfully to remote repository.

Comment: @Kishore then is the current failed commit much larger than that?

Comment: Initially I tried with 6-GB code where as it didn’t work, Later 662M & 1.4-GB code I could able to push successfully.

Comment: @Kishore OK. I have edited the answer with a possible solution then.

Comment: I feel some bug in GitLab latest version - `12.7.5-ee`.  Now i tried to push 2.7-GB code, but it failed

Comment: @Kishore Do you have  a `client_max_body_size` as in https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/issues/17917?

Comment: `client_max_body_size` not configured in `gitlab.rb` file.