# When rebasing, why doesn't git add --patch work?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-diff, git-add

In a git repository, I have a single file with a large commit I want to divide into multiple commits. I am trying to follow the instructions at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43138338) but I have run into a problem. `git status` shows that file.js is untracked, but `git add -p file.js` responds "No changes." 
I made a [github reposiotry](https://github.com/jgibbons94/rebase-error) to illustrate exactly what I mean.

In this specific repository, I want divide commit 92cc4839abe2bfe54981d8227c17acf07c24c84b into several commits, each adding one function to file.js. However, the only helpful instructions I have found fail.

How to reproduce:

1. `git clone https://github.com/jgibbons94/rebase-error.git`
2. `cd rebase-error/`
3. `git rebase -i HEAD~2` and mark commit 92cc483 to edit. Keep everything else the same.
4. `git reset HEAD~`
5. `git status` lists file.js is not tracked.
6. `git diff file.js` shows no changes.
7. `git add -p file.js` responds "No changes."

Is this a known issue with a known workaround? Am I misunderstanding something? All help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

> 4. git reset HEAD~
> 5. git status lists file.js is not tracked.

Commit `92cc483` *added* the file, so when you did a `git reset` to back out the copy of `92cc483`, this *removed* the file from Git's index.

Reminder: the *index* or *staging area* (two terms for the same thing) holds a copy of each file that will go into the *next* commit.  It's initially a copy of the *current commit*.  So `git reset HEAD~1` (or anything equivalent) means *take everything that's in the index out, and put in, instead, everything that's in `HEAD~1`*.  The file `file.js` *isn't in* that previous commit, so now it *is not in the index* either.

The `git add -p` command needs to have something in the index to patch against.  An empty file in the index suffices, and `git add -N` creates such an entry, so:

```
git add -N file.js
```

will let you run `git add -p file.js`.

This isn't really all that useful because the entirety of `file.js` will now show up as the patch.  You might as well open `file.js` in your editor, snip most of it out, write that back, and then—while the editor is still open—run `git add file.js` and then undo the snip-away part so that you have the whole thing.  You now have, in the index, the copy of `file.js` that you'd like to have:

```
$ vi file.js        # open file.js in editor
[snip]
:w
^Z                  # suspend editor - or, open another window to run git add
$ git add file.js
$ fg                # resume editor
[undo snippage]
:x                  # write and exit
```

The result of all of this is:

```
$ git status
interactive rebase in progress; onto 85aa6aa
Last command done (1 command done):
   edit 92cc483 A really big commit
Next command to do (1 remaining command):
   pick 3891479 Add description.txt
  (use "git rebase --edit-todo" to view and edit)
You are currently splitting a commit while rebasing branch 'master' on '85aa6aa'.
  (Once your working directory is clean, run "git rebase --continue")

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    new file:   file.js

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   file.js
```

I can now `git commit`, resume my editor, snip (less this time), write, suspend, `git add`, `git commit`, resume editor and undo snippage, etc., until I've made all the commits for each function.  There's no need to bother with the clunky `git add -p`.