# Splitting git commit to meet git push limits

Tags: git

I have two git remotes repo1 has git push limit of ~200MB and repo2 has a git push limit of 100MB. I pushed a branch with one huge commit of ~113MB to repo1 (obviously). While trying to push the same branch to repo2 it failed. What is my best course of action here so that I can have the same branch mirrored across two repos?

Comment: Is it a Github repo?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Break a previous commit into multiple commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217156/break-a-previous-commit-into-multiple-commits)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+split+commit