# Break a git commit apart during pre-commit

Tags: git, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit

I am interfacing with a system that processes builds based upon a comment.  Each file requires it's own comment, and I can capture the comment from a third party system.

The pre-commit script seems the best way to do this, as it wouldn't require any additional processes (such as an external script) to perform the operation.

Something like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217156/break-a-previous-commit-into-multiple-commits) seems appropriate.  And if I could do this after the commit, it would work.  However, I am trying to do this during the commit.

Ideally, the user would commit each file independently, but that doesn't happen.

My code in .git/hooks/pre-commit performs:
`git --diff-index --name-only HEAD`
I get a list of files and perform:
`git add filename  && git commit -m "unique comment" --no-verify` for each one.

However, if I run `git status` I get the following:

```
$ git status
On branch dev
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/dev' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        modified:   FINANCE/ACCTPAY/COBOL/RICK6.cbl

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   FINANCE/ACCTPAY/COBOL/RICK6.cbl
```

Is there something I should be doing?  If I run `git reset head` after the pre-commit, the problem goes away, but I don't want these users to run that command all the time, and it doesn't work within the pre-commit script.

Answer (score 0):

In general, while it's possible to do some limited modifications in the `pre-commit` stage, you definitely should not, and trying to make multiple commits is probably not going to work and run into contention over the index lock.  It may also blow away the commits you've made since the parent of the commit in `git commit` may not refer to the commits you've added.  In any event, the commit-within-a-commit is absolutely not supported and even if it works now, may well break at any time due to subtle changes in how `git commit` works.

The best way to solve this is to change how you do builds so that people can write meaningful, logical commits.  Tools should be flexible and do difficult work so that humans don't have to, rather than forcing humans to perform meaningless work to pacify the tools.  You could add a pre-build step to your build system to extract the comment and split the commit apart into separate files that are built one at a time (if that's required), rather than splitting the work in your repository.  In general, all difficult decisions about how and where to build should be handled in the build system and not affect the commit workflow.

If you absolutely must do something like this, you can write your own tool by reading individual changes into the index with a temporary file in `GIT_INDEX_FILE` and using `git read-tree` and `git update-index` to update your temporary index, then writing the tree with `git write-tree`, and finally creating a commit with `git commit-tree`.  These are the appropriate tools for scripting, but they are very low level.  `git commit` is not intended to be scripted, since it's a porcelain command.

If you adopt this approach, you'll likely need to enforce your commit workflow in your CI system so that users don't accidentally write commits with multiple files.

Comment: I am not disagreeing with you at all.  However, this is something I don't have any control over, so just trying to find a solution.  I may end up recommending they do the commits one by one.  Thank you for the information.